# Keras save function not working with ASCII character in file path

Tags: tensorflow, keras, path, ascii

I'm following the [Keras text classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification), the entire tutorial worked flawlessly. Next, I wanted to try the .save and .load function, that's where a problem occured.

The code line :

```
export_model.save('text_classification_model.keras')
```

Gives me the error :

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[89], line 5
      1 #The export_model.save('text_classification_saved_model') line will save your model in a format that can be later loaded using tf.keras.models.load_model('text_classification_saved_model').
      2 #It will create a directory named my_model containing the model architecture, weights, and any relevant configuration. You can specify a different directory or path as needed.
      3 #export_model.save('D:\Desktop\SavedModel\model2.keras')
----> 5 export_model.save('text_classification_model.keras')

File c:\Users\gui-r\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\gui-r\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py:19, in IncrementalEncoder.encode(self, input, final)
     18 def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x96' in position 3325: character maps to
```

I don't understand why, my working folder path is the following :

```
D:\Mon_Drive\Ingenierie_Mecanique\Info\IA\formation_ML_DL\Keras_Deep_Learning\Introduction\
```

I tried other path alternatives :

```
# With r'':
export_model.save(r'D:\Mon_Drive\Ingenierie_Mecanique\Info\IA\formation_ML_DL\Keras_Deep_Learning\Introduction\text_classification_model.keras')

#Forward Slashes :
export_model.save('D:/Mon_Drive/Ingenierie_Mecanique/Info/IA/formation_ML_DL/Keras_Deep_Learning/Introduction/text_classification_model.keras')

#Double backslashes :
export_model.save(r'D:\Mon_Drive\Ingenierie_Mecanique\Info\IA\formation_ML_DL\Keras_Deep_Learning\Introduction\text_classification_model.keras')
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  having same problem.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.  first, i enabled the more verbose traceback option in tf and that led me to the error - it is upstream in the part of the code where it opens the vocabulary file which it then crashes (your error) trying to write.

if you edit that tf file open code to make encoding utf-8 explicit it works

i posted further details here:

[tensorflow2 save_model method failing on encoding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470842/tensorflow2-save-model-method-failing-on-encoding-error/77471051#77471051)