# tensorflow2 save_model method failing on encoding error

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

using python 3.9 and tf 2.14, i am able to successfully run through the entire notebook posted here and successfully create the model, and have it make its predictions:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

notebook is here:
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow_docs/docs/site/en/tutorials/keras/text_classification.ipynb

except that when i try to simply save the model by calling

```
export_model.save("exported.keras")
```

i get ...

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x96' in position 3325: character maps to

partial trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 export_model.save("exported.keras")

File C:\python_39_venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py:19, in IncrementalEncoder.encode(self, input, final)
     18 def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x96' in position 3325: character maps to <undefined>
```

full trace to follow

the crash happens here:

```
    def save_assets(self, dir_path):
        if self.input_vocabulary:
            # Vocab saved in config.
            # TODO: consider unifying both paths.
            return
        vocabulary = self.get_vocabulary(include_special_tokens=True)
        vocabulary_filepath = tf.io.gfile.join(dir_path, "vocabulary.txt")
        with open(vocabulary_filepath, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join([str(w) for w in vocabulary]))
```

it fails on the f.write call.  i can in the meantime try to

1. identify which string it is that fails
2. try adding an optional encoding='utf-8' argument in the .open call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

adding encoding='utf-8' to that call fixed the problem.  i imagine this is an os thing - i am on windows ...

file is:
keras\src\layers\preprocessing\index_lookup.py

line 845...

```
with open(vocabulary_filepath, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
```